# Efficient way to check two different elements for different classes

Tags: jquery

My project has generated sets of HTML elements to which classes later get added.  I'd like to search in the sets to see if any element has the class `span1hr` followed immediately by an element that has the class `span0hr`, and if so, change both of those classes to `span1hrfor30mins`.

Here's a sample of what the HTML elements could look like:

```
<div id="programe1" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_2 row2"></div>
<div id="programe2" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_3 row3 span1hr">NCIS</div>
<div id="programe3" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_4 row4 span0hr">CBS Evening News With Scott Pelley</div>
<div id="programe4" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_5 row5 span1hr">NCIS: Los Angeles</div>
<div id="programe5" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_6 row6">Person of Interest</div>

<div id="programe6" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_2 row2 span1hr">Twisted</div>
<div id="programe7" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_3 row3 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe8" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_4 row4 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe9" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_5 row5 span1hr">Twisted</div>
<div id="programe10" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_6 row6 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
```

In this case, since `programe2` has a `span1hr` class and `programe3` has a `span0hr` class, I would want those classes changed to `span1hrfor30mins`.

One additional complication: as you can see, I have multiple sets of `row2` - `row6` classes, and need to do this search within each set of rows.

I have tried code like this, but would need to duplicate this for row2-3, row3-4, row4-5 and row5-6.

```
if($('.span1hr').hasClass('row3') && $('.span0hr').hasClass('row4'))
{
  $('.span1hr').each(function(i,e)
  {
    if($(e).hasClass('row3') && $(e).hasClass('.span1hr'))
    {
      $(e).attr('row3'); $(e).removeClass('span1hr').addClass('span1hrfor30mins');
    }
  });
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I have two points / suggestions:  First, you say, `I have two elements with the same id...`  Don't do that.  It's not valid to have multiple elements with the same id.  Once you have one id per element, your selectors will become much easier.  Second, it's perfectly ok - in fact, encouraged - to add another code block that shows your HTML.  That's much easier than figuring it out based on your textual description.

Comment: I understand what you just said, but the problem is i create the code to allow me to generate each different number at the end that come with each different element.

Comment: $('.mainWrap').append('<div class="row" id="row'+i+'"><div id="image'+i+'" class="channelList div_'+i+'_1 row1"></div><div class="rowSubPgm"><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_2 row2"></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_3 row3"></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_4 row4"></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_5 row5"></div></div><div id="programe'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_6 row6"></div></div><div class="clear"></div>')

Comment: i am sure you should know how to compare on two elements with two different classes to find it then change the class i actually want. I believe that there is something could be involving with the variable, integer or something else. i have no idea what one i should be looking for.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein do you know how i can check on two elements with different class that i can change on the class without using the loops?

Comment: Chris, I recommend you rewrite your question.  The edit I added doesn't mention span1hr or row3, and your suggested code doesn't show any loop.  There are a lot of people who will be happy to help, but you need to give them clean information.  If your HTML is generated, generate it, view source, and copy it on to here, so that we can work with the real information.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein i have update the html source in my first post, can you see it? hope you will be able to help me.

Comment: Chris, that html is much more helpful, and I'm sorry I keep sending your question back to you, but we're making good progress.  Using the html code you posted, can you give an example of what exactly you're trying to do?  Your code looks like it's searching for each row with class `span1hr` and class `row3` and adding the new class `span1hrfor30minutes`.  I'm not sure yet what you want with `span0hr` and `row4`.

Comment: I am trying to check on two elements with two classes, 'row3' with the class '.span1hr', 'row4' with the class '.span0hr'. if they return it true then i want find on the element with the class, e.g: 'row3' with the class '.span1hr' to change from '.span1hr' to '.span1hrfor30mins' using with the loops while finding on per div block that must match it. If I have two elements with two different classes, e.g 'row3' have a class '.span1hr' and 'row4' with the class '.span1hr' that don't match with two elements and classes then i want to ignore them. I don't want the class to get mess up.

Comment: Ok, I'm still working on figuring out what you want.  In this example that you've posted, since programe2 and programe7 are each `row3` `span1hr`, you want programe2's class to be `pgmFirstRow div_1_3 row3 span1hrFor30mins` and programe7's class to be `pgmFirstRow div_2_3 row3 span1hrFor30mins`? And it should do the same with programe4 and programe9?

Comment: No, I want the programe2's class to be `pgmFirstRow div_1_3 row3 span1hrFor30mins` and programe7's class to be `pgmFirstRow div_2_3 row3 span1hr`. That is because i want to check on between program2 and program3 that if program2 have a class `span1hr` and program3 have a class `span0hr` then i want to change the class in program2 from `span1hr` to `span1hrfor30mins` to do on loops while i want to ignore the others that don't match it. Each element `row2` `row3` `row4` have different id and some classes `span1hr` will have the same class. Thats why I want to match it while ignore the others :)

Comment: Ok, I think I'm finally getting there.  So your rule is: "For each set of row2-row6, find any row that has span1hr followed immediately by another row that has span0hr, and change that first row to span1hrFor30mins"?  What, if anything should happen to the span for program3 in this example?

Comment: Yes, I want to find in each of set row between row2 with a class ."span1hr" and row3 with a class ".span0hr" to change the class for each row while ignoring the other rows the don't match it. Do you know how I can do that and what code I should use to control on each row for the class that I want to change when I want to check on two rows?

Comment: And if `row4` had `span1hr` and `row5` had `span0hr`, you'd want to change those as well, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I want to find on two rows with two different classes and change on each class.

Comment: Ok.  I finally know what you're asking for.  I'm going to edit your question and rewrite it to concisely say what it took us 15 comments to get to.  Editing will hopefully start getting feedback from others, but my edit will be a total rewrite.  If you feel I'm missing anything major in the rewrite, go ahead and fix it up.

Comment: @Scott - upvoted for more patience than anyone else on SO ;)

Comment: Thanks Scott that will be very helpful if others can help me with this. If not I would have to start all over again. It would to me that you are a mod, I would like to ask can you please allow me to post a new question because I tried it and it won't allow me to do so. I haven't done anything wrong? :(

Comment: can anyone help me with this one please??????????

Comment: I'm very much not a mod, but you can post on meta.stackoverflow.com to ask why you're not allowed to post further, or possibly flag either your question or your comments to get moderator attention.  I may be able to work on this further, but am currently swamped at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you need to check the class of the next element if the current element has a certain class.

Since you are using jQuery try the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function.
Something like this

```
 $('.pgmFirstRow').each(function(index, element) {
   element = $(element);
   if(element.hasClass('span1hr') && element.next().hasClass('span0hr')) {
      element.removeClass('span1hr').addClass('span1hrfor30mins').next().removeClass('span0hr').addClass('span1hrfor30mins');
   }
 });
```